# creating divs inside divs like wikipedia

Tags: mysql, sql, wikipedia

i want to create a wikpedia like page. Let me explain what means wikipedia-like. As you know wikipedia has divs insidde divs [image]

i tried something like that to do the same thing

[image]

here my problem is i want `$divid= 1, 2 ,3` and inside `$divid=3` i want another 3.0, 3.1, 3.2. but it chooses `$divid=3` three times and i get three `$divid=3` divs.**What should i do if i want to choose `$divid=3` only once**

***NOTE: if you want to suggest different things fell free***

my sql query is:

```
$query_special = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM divs WHERE divid=$divid ORDER BY   divid2 ASC");
```

Comment: The picture you show is table of contents. Wikipedia doesn't store that in the database at all. It just generates it based on the headers in the rest of the document. Maybe a good idea for you too?

Comment: And if you do store it, I would store a structure, not divs. Divs are output.

Comment: @GolezTrol so where it store header files? the problem is i want to header files not table of contents. i show here table of contents cause i tought it is more easy to understand

Comment: The table structure is not really clear to me. Using this, you can only have two levels. And of course divid 3 is 3 times there, because it has 3 'sub-chapters'. That is something that is hard to solve in the database, but can be easily solved in you (PHP?) code. Also, if you want a truly nested structure, you would have to have items with a parent id, instead of your current table structure. Can you show the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get all divids uniquely.

Please try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT divid FROM divs
```

Then you will get 1,2,3,5,8

Comment: when i optimize it to my all code it didn't work. i write it like `"SELECT DISTINCT divid , divid2 FROM divs WHERE divid=$divid ORDER BY divid2 ASC"`

Comment: It cannot work in that way. Do you want to get records like 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3.0 3.1 3.2?

Comment: i want it like inside 1 there is no other div but inside 3 i want to create another 2 more div

Comment: I suggest the fields to be: divid, parentdivid, ...   so you can select children by SELECT * FROM divs WHERE parentdivid=$divid ORDER BY divid ASC